# libvirt-bin, ubuntu 19.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm

Я хочу установить kvm но последней версии ubuntu 19.4 утилиты libvirt-bin нет, установить невозможно ее, чем ее заменить или может есть иной способ установки этой утилиты?

Comment: при установке пишет сообщении, Пакет libvirt-bin недоступен, но упомянут в списке зависимостей другого
пакета. Это может означать, что пакет отсутствует, устарел или
доступен из источников, не упомянутых в sources.list

E: Для пакета «libvirt-bin» не найден кандидат на установку

Comment: в `libvirt-clients` по идее бинарники должны быть. Плюс `libvirt-daemon` и `libvirt-daemon-system` по зависимостям для биндингов к гипервизорам и `qemu-kvm` для собственно KVM

Answer (score 1):

Вместо `libvirt-bin` импользуйте `libvirt-daemon-system libvirt-clients`.

[Дубликат вопроса на askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089753/kvm-qemu-installation-issue-18-10); [Детальная инструкция по установке](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_19.04&p=kvm&f=1).